# Javascript autocomplete for textbox (not textfield)

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have an actual multiline textbox, with paragraphs of text in it.  I'd like autocomplete functionality, which would be activated by a tokenizing character (for example '#').  The autocomplete dropdown should appear "in-place" relative to the word being completed, rather than at the bottom of the box.

Of course, there are many excellent textfield autocomplete libraries such as the vanilla jQuery implementation.  But these all seem to be for a single value, as opposed to, say, for implementing in-browser spellcheck on a word processor.

Is there an autocomplete example for a textbox, rather than a textfield?

Any known libraries for this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'textbox'? Are you referring to the `<textarea>` element?